# Designing Generic Type Dropdown/Bottom Drawer component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns, typescript-generics

this is the first time I've run into an issue like this as I don't often use generics and was looking for some advice.

We have an existing Dropdown component in our codebase that takes in the following props:

```js
interface DropdownOption<T> {
  value: T; // the actual value you select when clicking on that option
  label: ReactNode; // what it gets displayed inside the 'DropdownItem' component
}
```

and then the dropdown component looks like:

```js
interface Dropdown<T> {
  value: DropdownOption<T> // the current value that the dropdown has selected
  options: DropdownOption<T>[]; 
  select: (option: DropdownOption<T>) => void; // select a new dropdown option
  isOptionDisabled: (option: DropdownOption<T>) => boolean;
  ...some other irrelevant stuff
}
```

Now my issue is that I've been tasked with implementing a Dropdown for our mobile design where instead of it being the traditional dropdown, now when you click on the dropdown a Bottom Drawer pops up (similar to https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/drawer). So really it's a clickable div that opens a bottom drawer.

I'm a bit unsure of how to proceed as I don't think either approach I've come up with is super clean.

1. My first idea was a sort of composable approach where I narrow down the type and make a specific component for each type of Dropdown that we have.

```js
interface NumberMobileDropdownProps {
  value: DropdownOption<number>; // Explicitly defining the type so that I have the proper type for when I want to pass the value to other components
  options: DropdownOption<number>[]; 
  select: (option: MobileDropdownOption<T>) => void;
}

export const NumberMobileDropdown = ({value, options, select}: NumberMobileDropdownProps) => {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      // Dropdown display
      <div onClick={() => setDrawerOpen(true)}>
        {value.label}
      </div>

      // Bottom Drawer
      <Drawer open={drawerOpen} closeDrawer={() => setDrawerOpen(false)}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          etc...
        <DrawerHeader />
        {
          options.map((tuple) => (
            <NumberDrawerItem number={tuple.value} />
          ))
        }
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. My other idea was to extend the original DropdownOption to also take in a drawerLabel that I could render

```js
interface MobileDropdownOption<T> extends DropdownOption<T> {
  drawerLabel: ReactNode; // what to render inside of the Bottom Drawer row
}
```

and then have something like:

```js
interface GenericMobileDropdownProps {
  value: MobileDropdownOption<T>;
  options: MobileDropdownOption<T>[]; 
  select: (option: MobileDropdownOption<T>) => void;
}

export const GenericMobileDropdown = ({value, options, select}: GenericMobileDropdownProps) => {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      // Dropdown display
      <div onClick={() => setDrawerOpen(true)}>
        {value.label}
      </div>

      // Bottom Drawer
      <Drawer open={drawerOpen} closeDrawer={() => setDrawerOpen(false)}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          etc...
        <DrawerHeader />
        {
          options.map((tuple) => (
            {tuple.drawerLabel}
          ))
        }
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but felt like this second approach could end up a bit weird because you either end up with some weird setup code in your caller component

```js
NUMBER_MOBILE_DROPDOWN_OPTIONS = [
  {
    label: <SomeLabelComponent />,
    drawerLabel: <SomeDrawerLabelComponent />
    value: 1,
  },
  //...gets repeated over and over, also seems painful if you want to deal with state
]
```

or you end up making a specific NumberMobileDropdown component anyways to abstract away that logic.

Would really appreciate any help/insight here. Sorry if it's a bit long, I tried to format it to be as palpable as possible.